# Javascript to server specific CSS for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I need to serve specific CSS for mobile browsers. I do not want to detect mobile browswers by media size or shape. I would like to do it using navigator.userAgent.match.

Here is a snippet of code i'm working with but doesnt seem to be working. The intent here is that the javascript would detect a mobile browser and supply the href for the mobile.css, otherwise serve up the normal css.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Home - Test code</title>
    <script>
        var text = "";
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {
            text = "'mobile.css'";
        } else {
            text = "'screen.css'";
        }
        document.getElementById('insertStyle').href=text
    </script>
    <link id="insertStyle" rel="stylesheet" href="null">
    </head>
```

Currenly the code doesn't work at all and just leaves the href for the stylesheet as "null". Any guidance as to how I can patch my code up would be much appreciated.

Comment: why do you have the ' and also the ". try to remove one of them

Comment: *"I do not want to detect mobile browswers by media size or shape. I would like to do it using `navigator.userAgent.match`."* That's entirely your choice, but I will note that using `userAgent` for this is generally considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: I thought that it html would need to see it in quotes also. I now know that isn't necessary to specify to the javascript. Thank you.

Comment: As for my chosen anti-pattern method, I feel like phones resolutions are getting pretty big, so this method is ideal to avoid potentially serving phones the wrong css based on large screen size.

Comment: Very retro to go browser sniffing...

Comment: Yeah, well phones are big, I dont wanna get tricked by a large screen size if I can help it.

Comment: You might be confusing screen resolution with CSS pixels, there's not a phone over 800 pixels in this list: http://mydevice.io/devices/. Feature testing's preferred these days in any case. User agent strings can be spoofed and aren't reliable either.

Comment: At the time of my post I wasn't aware CSS pixels were different from device screen resolution. The method I ended up using was a combination of browser sniffing, and "max-width" and "orientation: portrait" just to cover all bases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Remove the `'` in `"'mobile.css'"` and `"'screen.css'"`. You've *already* put the text in quotes, there's no need to do it twice.
2. Have the JavaScript add the element. Right now, when your code runs, the element doesn't exist, so you get `null` from `getElementById`.

So something along the lines of:

```
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.rel = "stylesheet";
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {
    link.href = "mobile.css";
} else {
    link.href = "screen.css";
}
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].insertChild(link);
```

Comment: Thank you.
1) I see now that I didnt need to double quote. I had assumed javascript would dump out the variable without quotes and that the html would need them also, thus I ended up doubling up.
2) I ended up just moving my script to take place after the link id="insertStyle".
Everything appears to be good now. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @Panopticon36: Yeah, the main thing to remember is that when you're dealing with the DOM, you're dealing with objects and properties, not HTML strings...

Answer (score 0):

The code I ended up using looks like this thanks to T.J. Crowder and thanks to the comments on my question. I ended up using browser sniffing, along with orientation, and max-width so that the style should switch properly under almost any condition.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Home - Finished version</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="stuff">
<meta name="description" content="more stuff">
<meta name="author" content="Me">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link id="insertStyle" rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css">
<script src="detectMobile.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation: portrait)" href="mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 700px)" href="mobile.css" />
</head>

<body onload="detectMobile();" bgcolor="#ffffff" White center no-repeat scroll;>
<a style="display:none;" href="#maincontent">Skip to main content</a> 
<a style="display:none;" href="sitemap.html">Sitemap</a> 
<div id=maincontent>Lorum Ipsum</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And in a separate file named detectMobile.js

```
function detectMobile() {
    var text = "";
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Playstation/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/mobile/i)) {
        text = "mobile.css";
    } else {
        text = "screen.css";
    }
    document.getElementById('insertStyle').href=text
}
```

Thanks everyone.